# xml parsing of file with double quotes with python

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing

i'm trying to parse an xml file with has some entries that has text with quotes inside.

Below is one line of the xml file as a sample.

```
<Video ratingKey="7459" key="/library/metadata/7459" studio="Paramount Pictures" type="movie" title=""Crocodile" Dundee" contentRating="PG-13" summary="When a New York reporter plucks crocodile hunter Dundee from the Australian Outback for a visit to the Big Apple, it's a clash of cultures and a recipe for good-natured comedy as naïve Dundee negotiates the concrete jungle. Dundee proves that his instincts are quite useful in the city and adeptly handles everything from wily muggers to high-society snoots without breaking a sweat." rating="6.3" year="1986" tagline="The Wizard of Auz hits The Big Apple!" thumb="/library/metadata/7459/thumb/1382989284" art="/library/metadata/7459/art/1382989284" duration="5352480" originallyAvailableAt="1986-04-24" addedAt="1382987525" updatedAt="1382989284">
```

When i use this simple code to read the xml file i get a error

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
tree = ET.parse('MovieList After HD Crash.txt')  
root = tree.getroot()  
print root.tag  
print root.attrib
```

The error is `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line ..., column ...`

Is there a different way to parse the xml file with these lines with extra quotes inside?

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the double quote using "

```
title=""Crocodile" Dundee"
```

will become

```
title="&quot;Crocodile&quot; Dundee"
```